# How to reduce size of the bar code. Zebra ZM600

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, zebra-printers

I have a problem with bar codes on labels. I have two Zebra printers ZTC ZM600-200dpi ZPL(unreadable code) and ZTC ZT420-300dpi. The problem is that one of them prints for long barcodes, which then can not be scanned by a scanner (screen). What may be the problem, I tried to compare the settings. I changed to identical and nothing. How to change barcode size?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that one of them prints for long barcodes

Do you mean the barcode length is too long and getting cropped/cut-off and that is why it is not scannable?

What software is generating the ZPL?  And what values are being set with `^BY`, which controls the module width of barcodes?  Since the 300dpi label is readable, it sounds like you need to reduce the module width set by `^BY` for the 200dpi label.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it really solves the problem. Now the question. How to set 300dpi on ZM600-200dpi printer?

Comment: If you are working with low-level ZPL and not a label generation package, you must design different labels for different dpi printers.  With ZPL, the size parameters are all in "dots".  So font sizes, graphics, bar code module widths and heights - virtually everything you want to put on a label - must be adjusted for the different print densities.